# Replace String to Int

Tags: ruby

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

filepath = "chapter1.xhtml"
text = File.read(filepath)


i=1

text = File.read(filepath)

while i!=91


replace = text.gsub(/123123/) do |match|
  match=i.to_s()
end
File.open(filepath, "w") {|file| file.puts replace}
    i=i+1
end
```

I want to replace Ruby1,Ruby1,Ruby1 to Ruby1,Ruby2,Ruby3
But My code doesn't work. Where is my fault and How can I fix it ?

For Example

Ruby1
Ruby1
Ruby1

replace to

Ruby1
Ruby2
Ruby3

Answer (score 0):

`text = File.read(filepath)` reads the whole file, so you read it again and again in the loop.

Idem for `File.open`, you erase the file 90 times.

```
My code doesn't work.
```

You should rather explain what happens, error message, etc.

Comment: Give me three lines of you input file, I can't help without more informations.

Comment: input file
<section id="bolum1">
<section id="bolum1">
I want to 
<section id="bolum1">
<section id="bolum2">

Answer (score 0):

```
input_path  = "chapter1.xhtml"
output_path = "new.txt"
#input = 'input file <section id="bolum1"> <section id="bolum1"> <section id="bolum1">'
string_to_replace = 'bolum1'
File.open(output_path, "w") do |output|
    File.open(input_path, 'r') do |f|
        f.readlines.each do |line|
            counter = 0
#            result = input.gsub(string_to_replace) do |match|
            result = line.gsub(string_to_replace) do |match|
#                puts "found=#{match}"
                counter += 1
                match[-1, 1] = counter.to_s # replace last char by counter
#                puts "replace=#{match}"
                match # the result of the block replaces the matched string
            end
            p result
            output.write(result)
        end
    end # input file will automatically be closed at the end of the block
end # output file will automatically be closed at the end of the block
```

File chapter1.xhtml :

```
input file <section id="bolum1"> <section id="bolum1"> <section id="bolum1">
input file <section id="bolum1"> <section id="bolum1"> <section id="bolum1">
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
"input file <section id=\"bolum1\"> <section id=\"bolum2\"> <section id=\"bolum3\">\n"
"input file <section id=\"bolum1\"> <section id=\"bolum2\"> <section id=\"bolum3\">"
```

I'm not sure this is the right solution because I don't know your input. Is it XML ? Using an appropriate XML library could be better. Is it more complex ? Maybe the input must be parsed with a grammar. See www.antlr4.org and http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference. The source code of the book is free and contains a grammar to parse XML.

Hope that helps. B